# Python Tkinter in ubuntu

Tags: tkinter

I am giving this command in ubuntu

```
def gui_c(self):   
    self.button1=Button(app,text="Search",command=self.search_())
    self.button1.grid()
```

I want to `search_()` function by clicking on this button.But before clicking this function has been called and self.button1.grid() is not executed.
Please help.

Comment: just add the word lambda before the function name. Something like this:
command=lambda:self.search_()

Answer (score 5):

To pass the function instead of executing it, get rid of the () brackets, so use `command=self.search_` instead of `command=self.search_()`

This is python's way of referring to the function itself.
For example:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print("Spam eggs bacon and spam")
... 
>>> foo()
Spam eggs bacon and spam

>>> foo
<function foo at 0x7f4dac4ec2a8>

>>> a = foo
>>> a
<function foo at 0x7f4dac4ec2a8>

>>> a()
Spam eggs bacon and spam
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write:

```
def gui_c(self):   
    self.button1=Button(app,text="Search",command=self.search_)
    self.button1.grid()
```

THis is a doubt that I had too, when I was new to Tkinter.